In a Excel Pivot how to get details of cell's grouped value like drilldown but with JavaScript API?
In an Excel Add-in that I'm working on I'm able to create a Pivot by the Excel JavaScript API from a Data worksheet and it works like a charm... but now I need to retrieve the single values from a total cell like when you drilldown with a double click.

I tried to navigate through the Pivot items and fields but with no luck.
Is it possible to get this grouped data source by the JavaScript API?
